# PHP / MySQL Detecting Price Column Change in Table

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

What's the best way to go about this?

My Table, `Listings`

```
+------------------+--------+-------+--------+
|      Title       | ItemID |  SKU  | Price  |
+------------------+--------+-------+--------+
| Product Title #1 |  02439 | AE-SM | 100.00 |
| Product Title #2 |  04923 | BX-MM | 200.00 |
+------------------+--------+-------+--------+
```

This information is taken from the eCommerce platform API once per day via a PHP script cron job.

Shopify is an easy example as the Listings data can be obtained from a json encoded URL

```
//connect to mysql database

$connect = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

$connect->query('TRUNCATE ShopifyListings;');

$shopifylistings = file_get_contents('https://secret:key@my-store.myshopify.com/admin/products.json');

$productsjson = json_decode($productsfile, true);

foreach($productsjson['products'] as $products) {

// decode variables to insert

$sql = "INSERT INTO Listings (Title, ItemID, SKU, Price)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$itemid."', '".$sku."', '".$price."')";

}
```

My task is to keep track of price changes in listings.

My first initial supposition was to create a new table `Listings_history`

```
+----+------------------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| id | Item_Identifier  | SKU | old_Price | new_Price |
+----+------------------+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

And then create a trigger such as

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER 'pricing_History' AFTER INSERT ON 'Listings' 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.Price <> OLD.Price) THEN
      INSERT INTO Listings_history (Item_identifier, SKU, old_Price, new_Price) VALUES(ItemID, Title, OLD.Price, NEW.Price);
  END IF
END;
$$
```

But of course this does not work as I am using a `TRUNCATE` statement to delete the contents of the table before inserting the new values, thus the `OLD.Price` is not obtainable.

What are my options? I suppose I could create a PHP script that uses a SELECT statement and references the current rows in `Listings`, then using an `UPDATE` statement to update the row if need be, and a `DELETE` statement if the row/product is not Listed (this way I can use the trigger above)

Is creating a `TRIGGER` like the above the best way to go about this? If so, must I revise how I am entering the data into my `Listings` table from an `INSERT` statement to an `UPDATE` statement?

Or is there a better more efficient way of doing this to keep track of price changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load the table, calculate *all* the changes in prices using a query like this:

```
select l.ItemID, l.Title, ph.new_Price, l.Price
from listings l left join
     (select ph.*
      from pricing_history ph
      where ph.id = (select max(ph2.id)
                     from price_history ph2
                     where ph2.item_identifier = ph.item_identifier
                    )
     ) ph
     on l.item_identifier = ph.item_identifier
where ph.new_Price is null or ph.new_price <> l.price;
```

You can just put an `insert` before this and insert all in one batch.

Note:  I would be expecting a date/time in the history table.

EDIT:

For performance, an index on `price_history(item_identifier, id)` would help.

A similar solution is not to use the price history, but to copy `shopifylistings` into `last_shopifylistings` and use that instead of `price_history`.  The subquery to get the most recent price change is then not needed.

Comment: Great! Didn't even think of doing something like this. So I insert all my `Listings` as of current into the `pricing_history` table... and then reference using the query above to check changes? I am testing it out and not getting a query result (phpmyadmin stuck on loading for several minutes)... something to do with the `SELECT` statements in parenthesis.. If I remove that portion I get a result set of all the `Listings`. Seems the query goes a bit wacky if there is only one `id` per `item_identifier`? Not sure still looking into it.

Comment: edit: Actually it did go through, after 287 seconds... my tables need to be further optimized for sure, but it shouldn't be a 5 minute long query, should it? After adding the initial to my `pricing_history` it is 15,000+ rows.. just simply trying the query without the left join - `SELECT * from pricing_history ph WHERE ph.id = (SELECT max(ph2.id) FROM pricing_history ph2 WHERE ph2.Item_identifier = ph.Item_identifier)` is taking over 4 minutes to get results from the query....